# Python-how to modify the code to stop monkey runner

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, monkeyrunner

Recently I have been running a performance testing program. But an error has 
bugged me for several days:

```
startMainActivityFromHomeScreen(com.google.android.perftesting.RunAppUIautomator)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService android.acessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub$Proxy@849d43balready registered!
```

Screenshot:
[image: error]

Since I can't find a reliable solution, I decided to modify the "run performance code(python)" in which it might change the result. I want to stop monkeyrunner to connect the service for temporarily.

```
# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
print 'Waiting for a device to be connected.'
device = MonkeyRunner.waitforConnection(5, device_id)
print 'Device connected.'
```

Screenshot:

[image: device connecting to monkeyrunner]

I don't really know where to start with. Can anybody give me a hint or something else to solve the problem?

[full code](https://github.com/testcorner/android-perf-testing/blob/master/run_perf_tests.py)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. It's usually a good idea to give the text of code and error messages, not images of them. When you post code and error messages as text, they are easier to find for search engines. This increases your chance to get help. Good luck!